# Custom iPhone "More" TabBarItem

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

Does anybody know how to rename the "More" tabBarItem?

In other words: How to access to this object?

Comment: just implement your own tableviewcontroller..

Answer (score 1):

Better you should use custom image and title for this, you should not look to modify the system items.

Comment: Thanks !

Where can I set custom title for this "more" tabBarItem ?